# Integer solutions to the inequality $\log_{1/5}\log_3\frac {x-3}{x+3}\ge0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$$\log_{1/5}\log_3\frac {x-3}{x+3}\ge0$$

If $x$ is of the interval $[-8,10]$

Now I solved this, tried to limit $x$ as much as I could but I consistently get that there should be $10$ values of $x$ for which this holds. The answer is a measly $3$, so I'm missing an important step.

I limited $x$ to $(-\infty, -6]\cup(-3,+\infty)$, whatever help that is to any of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\log_{1/5}$ is decreasing, so your inequality is equivalent to
$$
0<\log_3\frac{x-3}{x+3}\le 1
$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$
1<\frac{x-3}{x+3}\le 3
$$
The left hand side inequality is
$$
\frac{x-3}{x+3}-1>0
$$
or
$$
\frac{-6}{x+3}>0
$$
that gives $x<-3$.

The right hand side inequality is
$$
\frac{x-3}{x+3}-3\le0
$$
or
$$
-2\frac{x+6}{x+3}\le0
$$
which gives $x\le-6$ or $x\ge-3$.

Putting together the two inequalities gives, as solutions, $x\le-6$.

Note that your interval $x>-3$ is wrong. For instance, if $x=0$ you get
$$
\frac{x-3}{x+3}=-1
$$
and the logarithm is not defined. You forgot the condition that $\log_{1/5}t$ is defined only for $t>0$.

Comment: Right, I didn't think to include the left side of the inequality, and focused only on the right one. Thank you.